# How to call method from fragment only if host activity was destroyed?

Tags: java, android, android-lifecycle

I got a `method()` in the fragment. Fragment in host activity. So I need to call the `method()` from fragment ONLY when host activity was in `onDestroy()` . Maybe it suppose to be something like a static flag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can, by SupportFragmentManager, get a Fragment by layout id, tag or name.
But the most important thing here is in some situations Activity.onDestroy() method could never be called. So be careful if you implement code that needs to be executed, like an unsubscribe logic or removing callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyActivity:  AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        val fragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.my_fragment) as MyFragment
        if (fragment != null) {
            fragment.myMethod()
        }
    }
}
```

```
class MyFragment: Fragment() {
    fun myMethod() {
    }
}
```

Or use a ViewModel to handle communication between the activity and the fragment.

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing

Comment: thank you for an answer. But method suppose to be called IN FRAGMENT not in Activity. But only if activity was destroyed

Comment: what does "in Fragment" even mean?  why can't it be called on the Fragment from the Activity?